# Reloading TableView when JSON POST is Performed?

Tags: uitableview, afnetworking

I have a button in every UITableViewCell . I want to perform Refreshing the RowatIndex. Whenever the button is clicked. with performing the POST request method of AFNetworking . I have GET Request Method in my ViewdidLoad method .

How to update the data whenever the button is clicked in UITableViewCell with Loading Animation as Done is Basecamp Application ?

Comment: Your question is little bit vague, are you trying to update only the cell button pressed on it after your data source updated?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    NSMutableArray *cellIsRefreshed = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:yourDataArray];
    for(int i=0; i<[yourDataArray count]; i++)
     {
         cellIsRefreshed[i] = @"0";
     }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
      TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CELL_Identifier];
      }
      [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
      if([cellIsRefreshed[indexPath.row] integerValue] ==1)
      {  
         [cell.button setHidden:YES];
         [cell.doneImage setHidden: NO];
      }
      else
      {  
         [cell.button setHidden:NO];
         [cell.doneImage setHidden: YES];
      }
      return cell;
   }
- (void)buttonAction :(UIButton *)sender
  {
     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
     CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];
     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
     NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         cellIsRefreshed[indexPath.row] = @"1";
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
     [tableView reloadData];
  }
```

Comment: I don't have problem with 'GET' 'POST' 'REQUEST' , I am not able to show the acknowledgment for button selection like Basecamp application and data is not been refreshed.

Comment: have you tried [tableview reloadData]; after POST completed